# In MS SQL Server, is there a way to "atomically" increment a column being used as a counter?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, transactions

Assuming a Read Committed Snapshot transaction isolation setting, is the following statement "atomic" in the sense that you won't ever "lose" a concurrent increment?

```
update mytable set counter = counter + 1
```

I would assume that in the general case, where this update statement is part of a larger transaction, that it wouldn't be. For example, I think this scenario is possible:

- update the counter within transaction #1
- do some other stuff
  in transaction #1
- update the counter
  with transaction #2
- commit
  transaction #2
- commit transaction #1

In this situation, wouldn't the counter end up only being incremented by 1? Does it make a difference if that is the only statement in a transaction?

How does a site like stackoverflow handle this for its question view counter? Or is the possibility of "losing" some increments just considered acceptable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Read Committed Snapshot only deals with locks on selecting data from tables.

In t1 and t2 however, you're UPDATEing the data, which is a different scenario.

When you UPDATE the counter you escalate to a write lock (on the row), preventing the other update from occurring. t2 could read, but t2 will block on its UPDATE until t1 is done, and t2 won't be able to commit before t1 (which is contrary to your timeline). Only one of the transactions will get to update the counter, therefore both will update the counter correctly given the code presented. (tested)

- counter = 0
- t1 update counter (counter => 1)
- t2 update counter (blocked)
- t1 commit (counter = 1)
- t2 unblocked (can now update counter) (counter => 2)
- t2 commit

---

Read Committed just means you can only read committed values, but it doesn't mean you have Repeatable Reads. Thus, if you use and depend on the counter variable, and intend to update it later, you're might be running the transactions at the wrong isolation level.

You can either use a repeatable read lock, or if you only sometimes will update the counter, you can do it yourself using an optimistic locking technique. e.g. a timestamp column with the counter table, or a conditional update.

```
DECLARE @CounterInitialValue INT
DECLARE @NewCounterValue INT
SELECT @CounterInitialValue = SELECT counter FROM MyTable WHERE MyID = 1234

-- do stuff with the counter value

UPDATE MyTable
   SET counter = counter + 1
WHERE
   MyID = 1234
   AND 
   counter = @CounterInitialValue -- prevents the update if counter changed.

-- the value of counter must not change in this scenario.
-- so we rollback if the update affected no rows
IF( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 )
    ROLLBACK
```

This [devx](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/21570) article is informative, although it talks about the features while they were still in beta, so it may not be completely accurate.

---

update: As Justice indicates, if t2 is a nested transaction in t1, the semantics are different. Again, both would update counter correctly (+2) because from t2's perspective inside t1, counter was already updated once. The nested t2 has no access to what counter was before t1 updated it.

- counter = 0
- t1 update counter (counter => 1)
- t2 update counter (nested transaction) (counter => 2)
- t2 commit
- t1 commit (counter = 2)

With a nested transaction, if t1 issues ROLLBACK after t1 COMMIT, counter returns to it's original value because it also undoes t2's commit.

Comment: In your first example you mention that T2 could read, but would block on a write (makes sense).  However, an increment is a read and a write - you would not want to read then block on writing otherwise you would read the committed data (0), increment (1), then block on writing a 1 until T1 had written a 1.  I am guessing that the database will block the read here as well since the intent is to update.  Is that true?

Comment: @Travis In the initial example, there are 2 queries in different transactions updating the value (+1) in a single update statement (eg without reading it prior to update). N queries performing the same `counter=counter+1` update will block and the updates occur sequentially as the update statement escalates the lock already. There are locking hints and other mechanisms available should you require them. e.g. T1 issuing `SELECT counter FROM MyTable WITH(updlock) WHERE MyId = 1234` escalates the lock and would prevent T2 from reading until T1 is committed / rolled back.

Comment: @Travis is right. While the *user* isn't reading it prior to update, the database *is* reading it prior to update. One part of the execution plan goes out to read the current value, then it increments the value in memory, then it writes out the new value. Even adding `WITH(HOLDLOCK)` to the update just means that it holds that initial **read** lock - allowing another process to also read the current value. You an test the resulting lack of atomicity by having two batches in a while loop constantly running `UPDATE MyTAble SET Counter=Counter+1`

Comment: @IanBoyd I think you might be mistaken. I don't think I've ever seen this fail _when using a transaction_. For what it's worth, I have tested it with highly contentious production code and am satisfied it works for me. I'm sure others will appreciate you adding an answer with your own findings using different transaction levels, etc. Thanks

Comment: This answer is confirmed by a MS MVP [over here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8f4b1b6e-cdf0-45da-88a5-6d6059159121/update-set-fieldvalue-atomic-concurrency-safe-?forum=transactsql).

Answer (score 38):

According to the MSSQL Help, you could do it like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET counterfield = counterfield + 1 OUTPUT INSERTED.counterfield
```

This will update the field by one, and return the updated value as a SQL recordset.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. The value is read in shared mode and then updated in exclusive mode, so multiple reads can occur.

Either use Serializable level or use something like

```
update t
set counter = counter+1
from t with(updlock, <some other hints maybe>)
where foo = bar
```

Answer (score 1):

There is at heart only one transaction, the outermost one. The inner transactions are more like checkpoints within a transaction. Isolation levels affect only sibling outermost transactions, not parent/child related transactions.

The counter will be incremented by two. The following yields one row with a value of (Num = 3). (I opened up SMSS and pointed it to a local SQL Server 2008 Express instance. I have a database named Playground for testing stuff.)

```
use Playground

drop table C
create table C (
    Num int not null)

insert into C (Num) values (1)

begin tran X
    update C set Num = Num + 1
    begin tran Y
        update C set Num = Num + 1
    commit tran Y
commit tran X

select * from C
```

Comment: I don't believe the question was talking about nested transactions which, as you indicate, are handled differently.

Answer (score 1):

I used this SP to handle the case where name does not have a counter initially

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNext](
@name   varchar(50) )
AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Out TABLE(Id BIGINT)

MERGE TOP (1) dbo.Counter as Target
    USING (SELECT 1 as C, @name as name) as Source ON Target.name = Source.Name
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Target.[current] = Target.[current] + 1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name, [current]) VALUES (@name, 1)
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.[current];
END
```