# How to set two columns in SQL Server database as auto increment int with increment seed 100?

Tags: sql-server

How to set two column in SQL Server database as auto increment int with increment seed 100 ?

Comment: Assuming you mean in a single table, you can't. And more importantly, why would you want to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only have one identity column per table, however, there are some ideas and workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583973/using-a-trigger-to-simulate-a-second-identity-column-in-sql-server-2005/3584026#3584026)

**Simulation using a Derived Computed Column**

If both "identity" columns are synchronized with each other, or the second identity can be derived from the first using a formula, then a Computed Column might be applicable, e.g. if the second `identity` is offset by a constant from the actual Identity column:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD OtherIdentity AS RealIdentity + 100;
```

Where `RealIdentity` is the actual / original `IDENTITY` column.

[Computed Column derived off Identity SqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc2f8/1)

**Using an Independent Sequence**

Another alternative would be to use an [independent Sequence (Sql2012 and Later)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySequence START WITH 100;

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    RealIdentity INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    RandomCol NVARCHAR(100),
    FakeIdentity INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence
);
```

[Sequence SqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/def7b/1)

Answer (score 2):

Like nonnb says, you can only have one column marked as identity. However, if there is a mathematical relation between the two identity columns, you can use a calculated column.  For example, if the second `id` is equal to the first `id` plus 500, you could use:

```
create table t1 (id1 int identity(1,100), id2 as id1 + 500)
```