# Mapping between BIGINT in Sql with BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, biginteger

We are facing some issue in which when we try to map `BigInteger` in Java with `BigInt` in sql, its value got changed. We also try to convert it to `longValue` before mapping but it also failing as long could not able to handle its value. We tried with `toString()` and it got worked but is their any other workaround apart from using `toString()` ?

Comment: What ORM or mapper are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Java's `BigInteger` does not correspond with SQL Server's `bigint` - despite the similar names they are almost completely different:

- In Java, `BigInteger` is a type that represents an arbitrary-precision integer. Internally is is represented by a non-sparse byte vector that is free to resize as values increase.
- In T-SQL, `bigint` represents fixed 64-bit integers. The Java equivalent is `long`. Note that both T-SQL's `bigint` and Java's `long` are signed-types. It is an intrinsic type for a value that is natively handled by the host computer's hardware.

It's true that `BigInteger` can represent any `bigint` value, but the reverse is not true: you cannot store most `BigInteger` values in a `bigint` column.

As you say you're using `BigInteger` in Java as your canonical value, it means you cannot use `bigint` in your table, you should instead use `varbinary(n)` (where `n` is some reasonable upper-bound for the size of your `BigInteger` values, then use it like this:

```
yourTableRow.hugeValue = yourBigIntegerValue.toByteArray()
```

Where your entity class `yourTableRow`'s `hugeValue` member is of type `byte[]` which is compatible with `varbinary(n)` in T-SQL.

I advise against using `varbinary(MAX)` owing to how blob values are stored[1]. It is highly unlikely you'll encounter integer values beyond `2^128` (16 bytes) or even `2^256` (32 bytes) so you shouldn't need more than `varbinary(16)` or `varbinary(32)`.

If you know your numbers won't exceed `2^128` you'd be better off storing it as two separate `bigint` (64-bit) values:

```
COLUMN hugeValueUpper bigint NOT NULL,
COLUMN hugeValueLower bigint NOT NULL
```

And some Java to extract the upper 8 bytes and lower 8 bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = someBigIntegerValue.toByteArray();
if( bytes.length > 16 ) throw ...

yourRow.hugeValueLower = (long)bytes[ 0] << 56) | 
                         (long)bytes[ 1] << 48) |
                         (long)bytes[ 2] << 40) |
                         (long)bytes[ 3] << 32) |
                         (long)bytes[ 4] << 24) |
                         (long)bytes[ 5] << 16) |
                         (long)bytes[ 6] <<  8) |
                         (long)bytes[ 7]      );
yourRow.hugeValueUpper = (long)bytes[ 8] << 56) |
                         (long)bytes[ 9] << 48) |
                         (long)bytes[10] << 40) |
                         (long)bytes[11] << 32) |
                         (long)bytes[12] << 24) |
                         (long)bytes[13] << 16) |
                         (long)bytes[14] <<  8) |
                         (long)bytes[15]      );
```

And vice-versa to get values out.

[1] It is true that SQL Server will optionally store `varbinary(MAX)` values inline in a row if the value is small enough, but I would consider any `BigInteger` value that is too big to be stored in-row (and so would be moved to BLOB storage) as being symptomatic of an error situation, so setting a low bound on a `varbinary(n)` column means your program will fail-faster.

Answer (score 0):

Java's [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is an arbitrary length integer, limited only by available memory or implementation limitations, whereas [SqlServer's `BIGINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms187745.aspx) type is simply a 64 bit signed integer. You are likely experiencing truncation once the value stored in your BigInteger exceeds 2^63-1.

If you are dealing with values exceeding a signed 64 bit integer, you will need to resort to alternatives, such as using strings (e.g. `VARCHAR(MAX)`), or an array of bytes for storage.