# Insert data in to sql server data table

Tags: sql-server, increment, identity

I have one table called `customer_master` that includes a column called `cust_id` with autoincrement set to 1.

When we try to insert records its working fine and inserted records like `cust_id` 1, 2, 3 and 4 are inserted, but when an error is generated in the insert command we do a transaction rollback, this means that `cust_id` 5 is not inserted, but when we are insert another record, `cust_id` generates 6. It skips `cust_id` 5.

I want to set it up so that if any error is generated in the insert command the identity is not incremented.

We are using c# and sql server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

The reason SQL Server does this is for efficiency. If you need a sequence number without gaps you shouldn't be using `identity` you would need to implement your own scheme where concurrent transactions are blocked waiting for the next value just in case the initial transaction rolls back.

[The second query here could be used for that purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453411/sql-server-auto-incrementation-that-allows-update-statements/3462957#3462957). But do you really need this? If it is purely for aesthetic purposes my advice is not to worry about it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) to reseed the identity column after an insert failure.

*DBCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name, NORESEED )* returns the current identity value and the current maximum value of the identity column.

*DBCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name, RESEED, new_reseed_value )* sets the current identity value to the new_reseed_value.