# using Lock in Stored Procedure SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What I am looking to avoid concurrency in my stored procedure

here is my script, I am trying SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SP_GenerateNextReportID]
  @type nvarchar(255), @identity int output
   AS BEGIN
         SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    declare @id int;
    set @id =  IsNull((select LastUsedIdentity from   ReportProcessGenerator       where Type = @type), 0)
    if(@id =0)
      insert ReportProcessGenerator values(@type, @id +1)
     else
        update ReportProcessGenerator set LastUsedIdentity = @id +1 where Type = @type

    set @identity = @id +1
  END
```

Not sure is this a right way or not?

Comment: I think this will be prone to deadlocks. There is nothing stopping two concurrent transactions both doing the `SELECT` then blocking each other from going any further. There's a couple of approaches here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453411/sql-server-auto-incrementation-that-allows-update-statements/3462957#3462957

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `UNIQUE` index or a `PRIMARY KEY` on `ReportProcessGenerator.Type`, then your stored procedures will not be able to modify the record for the same type concurrently.

Note that you should use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` or `OUTPUT` clause to avoid deadlocks, as @Martin points out. With `SERIALIZABLE`, concurrent `SELECT` queries won't lift the shared locks which the `UPDATE` queries will not later be able to upgrade.

However, why would you want to maintain separate per-type identities? Usually, one identity which is unique across types is as good as multiple ones unique within types, the former being much easier to maintain.