# Atomic counters Postgres vs MongoDB

Tags: postgresql, mongodb

I'm building a very large counter system.  To be clear, the system is counting the number of times a domain occurs in a stream of data (that's about 50 - 100 million elements in size).

The system will individually process each element and make a database request to increment a counter for that domain and the date it is processed on.  Here's the structure:

```
stats_table (or collection)
-----------
id
domain (string)
date   (date, YYYY-MM-DD)
count  (integer)
```

My initial inkling was to use MongoDB because of their atomic counter feature.  However as I thought about it more, I figured Postgres updates already occur atomically (at least that's what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821468/sql-atomic-increment-and-locking-strategies-is-this-safe) leads me to believe).

My question is this: is there any benefit of using one database over the other here?  Assuming that I'll be processing around 5 million domains a day, what are the key things I need to be considering here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All single operations in Postgres are automatically wrapped in transactions and all operations on a single document in MongoDB are atomic. Atomicity isn't really a reason to preference one database over the other in this case.

While the individual counts may get quite high, if you're only storing aggregate counts and not each instance of a count, the total number of records should not be too significant. Even if you're tracking millions of domains, either Mongo or Postgres will work equally well.

MongoDB is a good solution for logging events, but I find Postgres to be preferable if you want to do a lot of interesting, relational analysis on the analytics data you're collecting. To do so efficiently in Mongo often requires a high degree of denormalization, so I'd think more about how you plan to use the data in the future.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Michael!!  Great advice ... as for how I'm using that data, it's relatively straight-forward.  There will be aggregate requests (i.e. get all counts for domain X) and then I'll also be figuring out growth rates as well.  That's really it.  I guess in theory I could also do deeper analysis (like the average # of counts per domain, etc), however that's not really my intent right now.